# Imbalance of matter (protons) over anti-matter?

Tags: cosmology

I often hear that the imbalance of matter (protons) over anti-matter of just 1 in a billion protons resulted in all of the matter left in our universe. Where did energy of a billion matter/anti-matter pairs which annihilated each other go?

Answer (score 2):

almost all of it went into the creation of a bath of high-energy photons that flooded space.